# Logical application and infrastructure diagram

Tags: diagram, infrastructure

We have been asked to produce a logical application and infrastructure diagram for an existing system which is in the process of been transferred to a different server.  After some searching on Google we have not found any guidance on what this sort of diagram should containing, does anyone have any links or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you need is to create **UML diagrams**, you can use CASE Applications like **MS VISIO**, **Enterprise Architect** (EA), **StarUML** for generating such diagrams.

- Component Diagram
- Logical Deployment Diagram

For reading more about UML see:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_deployment_diagram.htm

Comment: Thanks I think you may be right it is the only thing that looks about right.  I think part of our confusion is that this is a straight forward system taking in data and displaying it, while most examples we have found are for more complex systems with interactions with other systems.